# Booting from GRUB starts OK, but during the process it says: "Gave up waiting for root file system device."

Tags: debian, dual-boot, grub

Thanks to a helpful member here, I got out of GRUB RESCUE environment and now I am able to start a boot from GRUB. I have a dual boot Debian 9 (controls the boot process) and Windows 10 being the other possible boot.  After performing a simple overclock setup over the BIOS (MSI X399 motherboard), the computer is unable to boot "fully" if I can say it like that, as it seems it gets stuck finding the root file system (see the 2nd screenshot). Before the BIOS overclock, the system was booting happily with no root file system issues.

In the three screenshots you see:

1. the GRUB commands I applied to start the boot
2. the lines that followed on the screen as the machine is trying to boot. 
   You can see that the **boot gives up finding the "root file system"**,
   which I had set up at GRUB with the command:  `linux /boot....   root=/dev/sda6`
3. the folders I have and zooming into `/dev/`
   where obviously the `sda6` is not found. 
   In fact, there are *no* `sd*` entries.

Question: Is my original GRUB command: `linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-amd64 root=/dev/sda6` wrong, or is there something else that's not letting the boot go through?

[image: GRUB commands to boot]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think your initrd doesn't contain the driver for your hard drive controller. Boot with rescue cd, chroot to rootfs, edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` and `MODULES=all`; then regenerate initrd with `update-initramfs`.

Comment: Thanks for this lead. I will definitely look into making a rescue CD (USB)